# Plant Identification in China

Tags: identification, houseplants

I picked up these plants from various people when I moved here (Chengdu, China). I was wondering if anyone knows what plants these are (5 unidentified plants in total). I've linked it to my blog post since I can't seem to upload them. Scroll all the way down.

Plant 1:
[image]

Plant 2:
[image: https://travelhomelive.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/img_1008.jpg]

Thanks!

Comment: Pictures need to be under 2MB to be uploaded.  I resized them and added the direct link for you.

Comment: It is preferable to ask about each plant in a  separate question.

Answer (score 1):

First plant looks like some kind of heart-leafed bushy type philodendron.  The stem looks "dieffenbachia-ish" but I don't recall any [dieffenbachias](https://www.google.com/search?q=schefflera&client=firefox-a&hs=fe2&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=np&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=eAC_U7WGK8XvoATz14GwBg&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1315&bih=658#channel=np&q=dieffenbachia&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch) with heart shaped leaves like the one in your picture.  If it is a philodendron, it is difficult to say what the variety might be, as the plant you have pictured is not in very good shape and there are probably hundreds of philodendron house plant varieties.

Second plant is a [Schefflera](https://www.google.com/search?q=schefflera&client=firefox-a&hs=fe2&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=np&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=eAC_U7WGK8XvoATz14GwBg&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1315&bih=658).

Comment: The second plant is Pachira aquatica.